# iOS: MVVM-C ViewController super class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, mvvm, coordinator-pattern

I have MVVM-C arch. Each `UIViewController` has a `ViewModel` and `CoordinatorDelegate` to notify the `Coordinator` when navigation needs to be performed. The code that creates the VC repeats itself, and I thought it would be great to create a super class to unify all static funcs that create the VC. Like this:

```
import UIKit

class MVVMCViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var coordinatorDelegate: CoordinatorDelegate?
    var viewModel: Modelling?
    
    static func initVC(storyboard: Storyboard,
                       coordinatorDelegate: CoordinatorDelegate?,
                       viewModel: Modelling?) -> Self {
        let viewController = Self.instantiate(in: storyboard)
        viewController.coordinatorDelegate = coordinatorDelegate
        viewController.viewModel = viewModel
        return viewController
    }
}
```

All `CoordinatorDelegateProtocols` will inherit from `CoordinatorDelegate` and all `ViewModels` will be inheriting from `Modelling`.

But the subclassing does not work smoothly.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this model wouldn't work fine.

MVVMCViewController has hardcoded protocols as variable type, so You should have the same in your childVC.

To make it work as u want MVVMCViewController show be generic (but can be a lot of issues with it), like

```
class MVVMCViewController<T: Modelling, U: CoordinatorDelegate>: UIViewController {
    
    weak var coordinatorDelegate: U?
    var viewModel: T?

}
```

or add just casted properties to ConnectViewController

```
class ConnectViewController: MVVMCViewController {
    
    weak var coordinatorDelegate: CoordinatorDelegate?
    var viewModel: Modelling?
    var currentDelegate: ConnectViewControllerCoordinatorDelegate? {
         coordinatorDelegate as? ConnectViewControllerCoordinatorDelegate
    }
    var currentVM: ConnectViewModel? {
         viewModel as? ConnectViewModel
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your superclass `MVVMCViewController` defines two properties `coordinatorDelegate` and `viewModel`. If you just need to access them in your child class `ConnectViewController`, just access it normally. You don't need to define it again.

Also, in your parent class, you have `weak var coordinatorDelegate: CoordinatorDelegate?`. But in your child class (`ConnectViewController`), you redeclare the property with a different type (`ConnectViewControllerCoordinatorDelegate?`). That is illegal, even if it is a subclass of `CoordinatorDelegate`.

Hence, either

1. Rename the property in child class to avoid the conflict
2. Keep the name and the type, but add an `override` keyword for the property if you plan to add additional functionality in your child class
3. Do not declare the property again at all in your child class if you don't need to add additional functionality to it. Just access it directly.

Refer to how inheritance works in Swift over here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html